# How can i add multiple variable to a !== query

Tags: custom-post-types

i'm trying to add a taxonomy filter on multiple CPT linked to this taxonomy.

i'm good for 1 cpt at a time, but i'm definitly sure i can do much easyier with one function for all cpt.

actually i have cpt "region", and i wish to add more like "region2", "region3", how can i do this ?

my code :

```
if ( 'region' !== $post_type )
// xxx
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Like so,

```
if ( ! in_array( $post_type, array( 'region', 'region2', 'region3' ) ) ) {
// something
}
```